# Does the order of the directories listed in the Windows PATH variable affect system performance in any meaningful way?

Tags: windows, path, environment-variables

I've noticed that when programs add their directory to the PATH environmental variable, most append it to the end but a few add it at the beginning, before the windows directory. So it made me wonder, are there any noticeable performance implications to doing it one way or the other?

My gut instinct is that most PATH lookups are for system executables and if every PATH lookup checks each directory in order then there might be a small benefit to having the system directories up front, but I don't know if Microsoft is just smarter than that or if maybe it's just such a small difference that it's simply negligible.

Comment: Just noticed the Java SE installer adds the javapath to the beginning of the PATH… That's irky.

Answer (score -2):

Have you ever pulled up system configuration. Looked at what runs at start up? Bare basics is all I run at start up to stop computer lag. Also, when you look at your path. There are 3 different ways it can be set to run. I keep mine on custom. So I get to choose what runs and doesn't. It's your choice how to set your computer. However, the more drag and push on your computer works to process slower it runs.